# Getting the links from main wordpress website to wordpress blog manually

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have my wordpress site and a wordpress blog, the blog is subfolder of main website like http://www.wordpress.com/blog/

Now, i wanted to place the footer links of main website in blog footer, so that whenever i change the permalinks structure in main website then blog footer links also follow the same permalinks structure. I want to write a function like getpagelink and connect to main website database. i can get the page IDs of each post but how can i get the permalinks of that particular page.

Or is there any other way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you can get the permalink of any post ID (including pages) with the following code:

```
<?php $permalink = get_permalink( $id ); ?>
```

[See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).